# Limit of a natural log function

Tags: limits

Lim x-->0 ln((x^2)/16-x^2)

How can I take the limit of this? I can't apply L'Hopital because only the numerator is indeterminate. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the problem? This is not indeterminate. The argument of the log tends to $0^+$, hence the log tends to $-infty$.

Comment: @bernard try placing a backslash \ before infty.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $-\infty$. We have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x^{2})}{16 - x^{2}}.$$
When $x\to 0$, $\ln(x^2) \rightarrow -\infty$. Also, $16-x^{2} \rightarrow 16$.

Therefore, the answer is $-\infty$.